# Difficulty handling Promises in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise

Hi can someone take a look at my code? I am implementing authentication on a back end I am building as a side project to improve my understanding of JavaScript.

**I'm not sure why the promise from a mongoose find is returning undefined.**

I have two functions I need help with. One is a help function which will be passed to a controller.

```
 import db from '../models';
 import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
 import validateLogin from '../validations/login';
 import isEmpty from 'lodash/isEmpty';
 const loginController = {};

 loginController.login = function(req,res){
     validateLogin(req.body).then(({isValid, errors }) => {
     // isValid is undefined here
     // This is the problem
        if(isValid){
             // give token
           res.status(200).json({
              success: true,
             token: 'here is your token'
          });
       } else {
          res.status(401).json({
             errors
          });     
       }    
   }).catch(err =>{
        console.log(err)
   });      
};

export default loginController;
```

The other is the controller function itself that will issuse a token depending on whether the helper function returns a valid or not response.

```
  import validator from 'validator';
  import db from '../models';
  import isEmpty from 'lodash/isEmpty';
  import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

  function validateLogin(data){
      const {  userInput, password } = data;
      const errors = {};
      if(validator.isEmpty(userInput)){
         errors.userInput = 'username is required';
      }   
      if(validator.isEmpty(password)){
         errors.password = 'password is required';
      }   
      return db.User.find({$or:[{ username: userInput }, { email: userInput }]}).then(existingUser =>{
         if(existingUser.length > 0){
            // User exists, check if password matches hash
            const user = existingUser[0];
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password_digest).then(valid => {
               if(!valid){
                  errors.password = 'Invalid Password';
               }
               console.log('from prmomise');
               return {
                  isValid: isEmpty(errors),
                  errors
                };
             }).catch(err => console.log(err));
          } else {
             errors.userInput = 'username or email does not exist';
             return {
                isValid: isEmpty(errors),
                errors
             };
          }
      });
   }

   export default validateLogin
```

Comment: *Difficulty handling Promises* in real life as well :-p

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Promises are promises @Rajesh ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a `return` is missing for the `bcrypt` call:

```
return bcrypt.compare(password, user.password_digest).then(valid => {
    // password check and returning result object
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Without it your `validateLogin` function eventually returns a promise that resolves to `undefined`.

Comment: `eventually returns undefined` - no, `validateLogin` returns a promise ... this promise will resolve to `undefined` when the `.then` after `db.User.find` finishes :p

Comment: Thx, you're right, that's what I meant. I fixed it.

Comment: Wonderful! What a major slip up by me. I slent a solid two hours trying to fix this